# Question about UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a UiTableView and the first cell is only showing information. The following cells are going to push new viewControllers to the window.

I don't want it to be possible to click on the first one, but the second cell (indexpath.row == 1) to be the first cell to click on...

Is there some property I can set to make that first cell "notChooseable"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
if(indexPath.row == 0)
cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    return;
  }
  else {
    //perform pushing controllers
  }
}
```